# VSCode - escape dot in regex character set

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

`[.]` only matches literal dot, how to escape it, so I could do `[.\n]+` to match all characters and line terminators, currently, I'm using `[\n'/\w,\s]+` as a workaround.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Hmm, `[\w\W\n]+` or `[\s\S\n]+`  works I believe.  It'll match the whole block of text though - probably not what you expect/want.

Comment: @Mark I'm actually using [\n'/\w,\s]+ as workaround

Comment: It appears you want to match everything including newlines, i.e like the `s` [DOTALL](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall) modifier in other regex engines. However, VS Code's search is JavaScript-based and hence does not support this modifier. As a workaround, you can use the "catch-all" class `[\s\S]+` This will select everything.

Comment: @Mark, line terminators are whitespace characters and non-word characters, so `[\s\S\n]+`,  `[\w\W\n]+`, `[\s\S]+` and `[\w\W]+` are all the same.

Comment: @wp78de [\s\S]+ can be a good workaround, thanks. But [ES2018 added the s "dotAll" flag, which allows the dot to also match line terminators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), does this oppose to "However, VS Code's search is JavaScript-based and hence does not support this modifier."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to match everything including newlines, i.e like the `s` DOTALL modifier in other regex engines. However, VS Code's search is JavaScript-based and hence does not support this modifier.

As a workaround, you can use a "catch-all" class: `[\s\S]+` or a similar double-negation like  `[\w\W]+`. This will select everything.

A note regarding the remark on the dotAll flag in ES2018/es6; unfortunately, this feature is not enabled in the current version of VS Code and adding the proper modifier `(?s)` does nothing:

[image]